# Disable Identity Toolkit when using Firebase Authentication

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-identity-toolkit

I just set up a new project for Firebase and it is requiring me to enable Identity Toolkit API.

This is a problem because, even though I'm wrapping the `firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword()` in a try catch, the Identity Toolkit still posts and I can't catch the error.

It causes security risks like this when displaying post error.

```
errors: [{message: "EMAIL_NOT_FOUND", domain: "global", reason: "invalid"}]
```

Which means a malicious user could try to log in until they don't get this error message to see if an email exists.

I have looked through https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/migrate-firebase but I am not clear on what it is trying to do.

The other problem is it costs money:

`Free
price/count
0 - 50K
count/month`

`$ 0. 0055
price/count
50K - 100K
count/month`

How can I use Firebase *without* the Identity Toolkit?

Comment: Are you migrating from Google Identity Toolkit to Firebase Auth? If so, it is free. If you are migrating to Google Cloud Identity Platform, the latter is not free.

Comment: @bojeil I am just trying to use Firebase Auth. I wasn't using Google Identity Toolkit in the first place. I had set up a new project and now it got enabled somehow?

Comment: @moto Did you get a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This change should be done by the Cloud Identity Platform engineering team and you need to create a private ticket in the [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=1120279&pli=1&template=1630021)

Answer (score -1):

##### Use fireabase CLI

Please install **firebase-tools**
Please check this url
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli